Why is GitHub Copilot Chat Inline not working despite Copilot and Copilot Chat functioning correctly?
I’m using Visual Studio Code with the GitHub Copilot and GitHub Copilot Chat extensions installed. While both Copilot (inline suggestions) and Copilot Chat (via the side panel) are working fine, the Copilot Chat Inline feature does not work.
Here are the details of my setup:

VS Code Version:

Version: 1.96.2
Commit: fabdb6a30b49f79a7aba0f2ad9df9b399473380f
Date: 2024-12-19T10:22:47.216Z
Electron: 32.2.6
ElectronBuildId: 10629634
Chromium: 128.0.6613.186
Node.js: 20.18.1
V8: 12.8.374.38-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.8.0-49-generic


GitHub Copilot Extension Version: Version
1.254.0

GitHub Copilot Chat Extension Version: Version
0.23.2

Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04

Keybinding for Inline Chat: Ctrl + I is assigned to Inline Chat:


{
  "key": "ctrl+i",
  "command": "inlineChat.startWithCurrentLine",
  "when": "editorFocus && github.copilot.chat.editor.enableLineTrigger && inlineChatHasProvider && !editorReadonly && !inlineChatVisible"
}

What I’ve Tried:

Verified that Copilot and Copilot Chat are enabled and working.
Checked keybinding for Inline Chat: Inline Chat: Start in Editor with Current Line is set to Ctrl + I and no other keybindings are set to Ctrl + I.
Ensured the GitHub Copilot Chat extension is installed and up to date.
Checked for logs in the Output Panel under GitHub Copilot Chat but found no errors.
Restarted VS Code and reinstalled the extensions.

Observations:

Highlighting text and pressing Ctrl + I does nothing.
Just pressing Ctrl + I does nothing.

Questions:

Is there a known issue with the Copilot Chat Inline feature in recent versions of the GitHub Copilot extension?


any chance if you can try VSCode in Codespace? If Codespace can listen Ctrl I then it probably your local VSCode issue. Another approach is try to install VSCode Insider
